# I need to find permutation of natural numbers such that abs(pos[i]-i==k) where k is constant for all natural nos

Tags: python

```
if n=4
first natural numbers are [1,2,3,4]
we could rearrange to [3,4,1,2]
so that pos[i]-i==2 for every natural no
```

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/absolute-permutation/problem

t are the test cases

```
def absolutePermutation(n, k):
        for i in range(t):
            pos=[]
            for j in range(1,n+1):
                if(j+k<=n):
                    pos.append(j+k)
                elif(j==k):
                    pos.append(j)
                else:
                    pos.append(j-k)
        if all(abs(pos[x]-(x+1))==k for x in range(len(pos))):
            return pos
        else:
            return [-1]
```

for 10 5

output

> 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5

for 10 1

i am getting wrong answer
expected output

> 2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 10 9

Comment: In the explanation at the top, I think you want `abs(pos[i] - i)`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is partial, It works only if n/k is an even integer, I'm not sure if there exists a solution if n/k is not even

```
n=20
k=5
naturals = list(range(n))
permu = []
for i in range(0,(n//k), 2):
    permu += naturals[(i + 1) * k:(i + 2) * k]
    permu += naturals[i * k:(i + 1) * k]
print(permu)
check = [permu[i] - i for i in range(n)]
print(check)
```

outputs

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5]
```

This worked also for n=4, n=8, k=2 (as in your example)

Comment: I didnt get your solution

Comment: Woops, had a mistake there, i'll be right back if i'll manage to fix it